# Не хочет установить id сессии в куки

Tags: php, сессия

В чем может быть дело, когда в куки не записывается id сессии?

При каждом обновлении страницы id сессии обновляется...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) нет места для хранения файлов сессии (тут в логах это видно должно быть) 2) какое то ПО режет куки входящего запроса и сервер заново стартует сессию (тут вы вообще ничего не узнаете) (такое могут делать всякие кэширующие штуки)

Comment: кстати определитесь, "не записывается", или "не принимается". Отдачу куки можно определить просмотрев заголовки ответа сервера в инструментах разработчика. Если куки нет в ответе, тогда резонно говорить, что она не создается. Если же она есть, и со следующим ф5 уходит в исходящем запросе, но в ответ приходит новый идентификатор, то копайте в сторону варианта 2.

Comment: ну и перед стартом сессии можно глянуть `_COOKIE`. если там пусто, то кука порезалась на входе (если была отправлена с запросом)

Comment: а если таки "не принимаются" то у клиента мб куки отключены в браузере

Comment: Нашел папку, что это за огромные файлы, сессии понятно, но что за 3 файла чуть ли не по гб. Что за конфиг, где указываем размер диска отдаваемого под сессии?

Comment: хз что за огромные файлы. если папка используется для аплоадов файлов, то это просто временные файлы, что было загружено, и по какой-то причине не почищены. Отдельной настройки в пхп для лимита размера сессий нет. на практике я утыкался, что просто физически закончилось место на диске. Хотя возможно можно установить какие-то квоты на уровне ОС и пользователей (но это маловероятный сценарий).

Answer (score 1):

При старте сессии кука с идентификатором отправляете клиенту и потом путешествует с каждым запросом туда-сюда.

Если с каждым запросом стартует новая сессия, следовательно кука где-то теряется. Вопрос в том, где именно. Может быть два пути - либо она не принимается клиентом, либо не доходит до сервера (*в прочих вариантах скорее всего вы получите варнинги или ошибки в логе пхп (так что изначально при любой диагностике сначала смотрим логи)*).

Откройте консоль браузера и гляньте в запросах, если кука уходит на сервер, то очевидно, она принялась, и на стороне клиента проблемы нет.

Далее посмотрите, принимается ли кука на сервере. Перед стартом сессии проверьте массив `$_COOKIE`. Если он пуст, то кука не дошла до пхп. Это может быть вызвано каким-либо кэширующим сервером на пути перед обработчиком пхп (в общем говоря, кто-то режет куки на этапе от получения сервером запроса, до фактической передачи запроса обработчику пхп (формально там может быть целая цепочка серверов)). В этом случае вы не увидите никаких ошибок в логах и т.п., запрос просто отфильтрован ранее и пхп ничего об этом не знает.

Но может быть ситуация, и когда дисковая квота израсходована, и при старте сессии пхп не может физически создать файл на диске, чтобы записать данные сессии. (либо другая квота (или ошибка записи), если сессии хранятся не в файлах, а в БД, например).
в этом случае, скорее проблему поможет определить просмотр логов (либо уровня приложения, либо уровня самого пхп)

---

банально если до старта сессии уже был ввод тела ответа, то заголовки вместе с куками уже не могут быт отправлены. так что формально это тоже можно отнести к этому вопросу. но в данном случае в логах пхп будут явные записи об этом (headers already sent)

Comment: С дисковой квотой все норм, свободно как минимум 100гб.

Comment: Вчера изменил конфиги, изменил имя с  PHPSESID на SID и время хранения сессии с 1440 на 250000. Больше ничего не трогал, в куках браузера клиента ни PHPSESID ни SID нету. При каждом обновлении страницы, создается новый файл сессии

Comment: И перезагрузил сервер

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов в заголовках ответа сервера в запросе тоже нет? а до смены работало (какой смысл менять-то был)?  смотрите логи пхп

Comment: Ошибку нашел по заголовку. Старт сессии переносил на пару строчек выше, поставил на которой задавал переменную домен на которой устанавливал куки... `session_set_cookie_params(null, '/', ".".DMN);` По умолчанию возможно прописать в конфигах, что параметр необходимо устанавливать на все поддомены, чтобы в php не прописывать данный параметр?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов все то же самое вы можете установить в самом конфиге https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

Comment: Это понятно, но как указать параметр так, что куки необходимо устанавливать на все поддомены при этом не привязывая параметр к конкретному домену? То есть при создании следующего сайта, все было то же самое...

Comment: если домены меняются, то в пхп прописывать, получая основной домен и $_SERVER